# Typische Fehler: Wörter, bei denen man denkt, sie großschreiben zu müssen

Tags: capitalization

Ich bin kürzlich auf ein paar Wörter gestoßen, bei denen ich gedacht habe, dass man sie klein schreibt. (Zahlenwörter, Objektnamen, ...).

Könntet ihr eine Liste von typischen Groß- /Kleinschreibungsfehlern oder viel mehr: Regeln zu nennen? Entweder als Antwort oder als Link.

Es ist deswegen nicht möglich, alle Groß- bzw. Kleinschreibfehler, die mich interessieren, zu nennen, da ich nicht alle kenne. Deswegen wollte ich hier fragen, ob ihr eine generelle Liste zusammenstellen könntet, um die häufigsten Fehler zusammenzufassen.

Hier ein paar:

> Mir ist es vier mal passiert. (vier vs Vier) Das ist das Goldene
>
> Dachl. (golden vs Golden) Ich habe dir Folgendes zu berichten. (das
> Folgende vs folgendes)
>
> Ich gehe am Montagmorgen fort. Ich gehe immer
> montagmorgens nach draußen.
>
> Ich schaue, dass ich morgen früh
> rauskomm'. Ich schau, dass ich am Morgen rauskomm'.
>
> Im Großen und Ganzen (großen vs Großen, ...)

Comment: Woher sollen andere Leute wissen, was du denkst, was man klein oder groß schreibt?

Comment: Generell weiß man denk ich ein paar Wörter die relativ oft falsch geschrieben werden

Comment: [Deutsche Rechtschreibregeln](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_veroeffentlicht_2017.pdf), hier Teil D: Groß- und Kleinschreibung

Comment: [Duden: Groß- und Kleinschreibung](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung)

Comment: Hier noch ein Artikel über häufige Fehler: https://www.annika-lamer.de/rechtschreibfehler-grossschreibung-kleinschreibung/

Comment: Zahlwörter werden aber nur dann groß geschrieben, wenn sie eine Ziffer bezeichnen. "Eine Acht im Rad haben" oder "Der Typ ist so eine Null". Ansonsten werden sie klein geschrieben: "Die zwei Gesellen" oder "Alle viere von sich strecken".

Comment: Gib doch bitte in der Frage ein paar Beispiele für solche Wörter, bei denen du über Groß- und Kleinschreibung gestolpert bist.

Comment: Habe meine Frage korrigiert!

Comment: Habe gegen Wiedereröffnung der Frage gestimmt, weil die Antwort eine zwangsläufig unvollständige Liste ist, die außerdem von Person zu Person unterschiedlich aussähe. Außerdem ist die Großschreibung (im **W**esentlichen) eine Frage, die sich mit Grammatik klären lässt.

Comment: Außerdem hilft eine solche Liste anderen Nutzern nicht (im Sinne von Stackexchange), denn wenn man bei einem Wort nicht sicher ist, sucht man nach diesem Wort, nicht aber nach einer Liste mit schwierigen Wörtern. Eine solche Liste führt der Duden übrigens auch (allerdings nicht auf Großschreibung bezogen): https://www.duden.de/Liste-der-rechtschreiblich-schwierigen-Woerter

Comment: Ich frage nicht nach einer vollständigen Liste, sondern einfach nach typischen Groß- und Kleinschreibfehlern. 

Es wäre schön, eine einfache Liste zu bekommen mit Regeln (dafür brauche ich nicht ALLE Wörter).

z.B. Regeln wie : Objektnamen, Wann Zahlen großgeschrieben werden, groß mit welchem Artikel (dem, im, ...)

Diese Regeln sollten doch nicht so viele sein (denk ich mir).

Comment: Ich suche also nicht nach einer Liste von Wörtern, sondern nach eine Liste von häufigen Fehlern (und daher: Regeln)!

Answer (score 5):

Die Frage ist ein bisschen sehr breit, aber hier wären ein paar Beispiele für Problemfälle der Groß- und Kleinschreibung aus der guten alten Zeit vor der Rechtschreibreform.

Darum aber auch: Achtung! Diese Antwort hat fast **nur noch historischen Wert**, weil genau diese Problemkinder der deutschen Rechtschreibung ja mit der sog. Rechtschreibreform wegerzogen wurden... meistens jedenfalls.

> Bescheid wissen, geben, sagen, tun (nicht bescheid) [neu: dito]
>
> deutsch reden [neu: dito]
>
> auf deutsch [neu: auf Deutsch]
>
> fließend Deutsch sprechen [neu: dito]
>
> ich möchte dir folgendes berichten [neu: Folgendes]
>
> ich möchte dir das Folgende berichten [neu: dito]
>
> Bezug nehmen [neu: dito]
>
> in bezug auf [neu: in Bezug auf]
>
> mit Bezug auf, unter Bezug auf [neu: dito]
>
> im allgemeinen [neu: im Allgemeinen]
>
> im besonderen [neu: im Besonderen]
>
> sich auf das Wesentliche beschränken [neu: dito]
>
> im wesentlichen [neu: im Wesentlichen]
>
> um ein wesentliches [neu: nicht mehr zu finden]
>
> außer acht lassen [neu: außer Acht]
>
> aus aller Acht lassen [neu: dito]
>
> von nahem [neu: von nahem/von Nahem]
>
> aus nah und fern [neu: dito]
>
> im großen und ganzen [neu: im Großen und Ganzen]
>
> aufs Ganze gesehen [neu: dito]
>
> Recht sprechen [neu: dito]
>
> recht haben [neu: Recht haben/recht haben]
>
> alles in allem [neu: dito]
>
> da gibt es kein Wenn und Aber [neu: dito]

(Quelle: meine eigene Sammlung solcher Fälle aus meiner Zeit als Zeitungsredakteur in den frühen 1990er Jahren. Der Karton mit diesen Wörtern lag hier noch griffbereit in meinem Duden Universalwörterbuch, 2. Auflage 1989, aus dem die Schreibungen auch stammen. Hinzugefügt in [eckigen Klammern] sind die Schreibungen, wie sie im gleichen Buch, 8. Auflage 2015, verzeichnet sind.)